# Vector Magnitude Equality 2

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I want to show that:
$$(n \cdot \nabla n)^2=(n \times \nabla \times n)^2$$
$n$ is a unit vector and $-n$ is essentially $n$ for this application. Using the vector triple product I can get the inner argument of the RHS to become:

$(n \times \nabla \times n)^2= [\nabla(n \cdot n)-n (\nabla \cdot n)]^2
=[-n (\nabla \cdot n)]^2=[n (\nabla \cdot n)]^2$

Using the definition of the dot product I get:

LHS = $[|n||\nabla n|cos\theta]^2=|\nabla n|^2cos^2\theta$
$$$$
RHS = $[n|\nabla||n|cos\theta]^2=n^2|\nabla|^2cos^2\theta$

So (if I'm on the right track of course) is $n^2|\nabla |^2=|\nabla n|^2$ necessarily?

Comment: $n^2|\nabla|^2$ doesn't make sense as a number, so you're certainly doing something wrong...

Comment: Exactly. Any suggestions on how to proceed?